# How can I detect if player is holding only 1 item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically, I am making a Minecraft map, and I want to detect if player is holding exactly one empty bottle. I tried to add `Count:1b` but it didn't work.
My command:

```
/execute if entity @a[distance=..2,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:glass_bottle"},Count:1b}] run setblock ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:redstone_block
```

What I need to do? I'm on Minecraft Java 1.19.

Comment: Your command doesn't actually include `Count`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, but I did like that (like how i edited it) and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the player for `Count`, not the item. `}` is in the wrong place.

```
execute if entity @a[distance=..2,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:glass_bottle",Count:1b}}] run setblock ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:redstone_block
```